# Python json parsing code needs refining

Tags: python, json

I am new to python so I decided to write a script that parses a json array and writes data in a file.

I wrote the code that does that but I think it can be done way better, So I was hoping to get feedback on how this code can be enhanced and more inline with python best practices.

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json

def get_json(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(data)


url = ("http://api.goeuro.com/api/v2/position/suggest/en/Berlin")
json_array = get_json(url)

f = open('data.txt', 'w')


for x in json_array:
    gp = x["geo_position"]
    l = gp["latitude"]
    o = gp["longitude"]
    f.write(unicode(x["_id"]).encode("utf-8") +", " +     unicode(x["name"]).encode("utf-8") + ", " + unicode(x["type"]).encode("utf-8")+ ", " + unicode(l).encode("utf-8") + ", " + unicode(o).encode("utf-8") + unicode("\n").encode("utf-8"))

f.close()
```

Also, what is the best way for not having an empty new line at the end of the file ?

Comment: You need to ask this question at: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, while [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) might be a good place to suggest going for this type of question, we should get out of the habit of sending question-askers over there. Please read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) meta post for clarification.